# Server-side Blazor vs MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, blazor, blazor-server-side

From a developer's perspective (and not from an architectural one) I don't seem much of a difference developing between Asp.net MVC and Server-side Blazor apps.

In fact, the server-side Blazor feels almost identical to MVC excluding some of the convenient data-bindings you can do in the blazor views/pages.

> Is there a major difference that I may not be aware of? Again, purely
>   from a developer's perspective, not from the underlying technology
>   perspective.

Comment: In Blazor you can handle MouseOver and KeyDown events.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The biggest advantage to server-side Blazor over MVC is that you will be getting the behavior of a single page application (SPA), i.e. rich feeling app with no full page postbacks.

Also in Blazor you are developing components and not Views. Now depending on how you structure you code this may not be of interest, but usually components lead to smaller reusable chunks of UI as opposed to views which tend to be whole pages.

There are potentially more things but they are very opinion based so I'm omitting them here. I hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I understand, and correct me if I'm wrong, another major difference is the differencing engine on the client that uses signalR to notify the server of changes to the DOM, and therefore only re-renders the affected DOM elements rather than the whole page.

Comment: Now that .NET MAUI is officially released, now another advantage is that you can host a Blazor app / component in a Blazor Viewer.